# Display a list from an Website in a Java Application

Tags: java, html, display

I know how to Display a Website in Java, but i want specific Elements of the HTML Website to be taken and shown, a example is csgolounge.com, where Matches are shown on the right Hand side, i want to remove the whole Website from my Java App, but i want to Show just all the Matches and if the Website adds Matches how can i make the App to automatically add the Match to the App?

My Knowledge really doesnt reach that far :/

Im not posting a Code because i probably Need something more advanced.

Thank you for every answer, Wip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this by using the [Jsoup library](https://jsoup.org/). An example of an extraction would be:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

With the above you are obtaining the doc and scrubbing it for a particular ID, with that you can then manipulate.